# Write a message on a starting position

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a message on a starting position that I have it stored to the textarea.

My textarea will have a maximum of 120 char, I want as soon as I click on the button get a message 'hello' on the position 100.

Is there a way to do it?

This is my initial code:

```
newmes = newmes.substring(0, selecStart)+ newmes.substring(selectEnd, newmes.length)+'\n'+'\n'+'\n'+'\n'+'\n'+'\n'+this.hello;
```

For the moment this is a trick. But it's not working well.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: So you're wanting to insert the word 'Hello' into a block of text that already exists within your `textarea` starting at 100?

Comment: My textarea is limited to 120 char, so i want as soon i click on the button the hello will be on the position 100.
Imagine i wote "Hello i need you help to solve my problem with the position of the string"
i need the hello to be on the position 100 even if the text exist

Comment: What happens if the text has a length of 95? Will the text 'hello' show?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO  yes

Comment: So the 'hello' message will show once they hit the 100th character.

Comment: Nooo , imagine you write a message and you want to have a signature, so when you click on the button the signature will be on the position 100